# Osm2pgsql failed Cannot detect file format. Try using -r

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, pbf

I use Osm2pgsql 1.0 and this my action :

```
sudo osm2pgsql --slim -c --cache 29000 --proj 3857 russia-latest.osm.pbf  -H  xxxx.local -d osm -U osm_user -W -P 5432
```

was failed after some time:

```
Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: Cannot detect file format. Try using -r.
```

Log in console betwen starting osm2pgsql and error displaing:

```
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Sharing dense sparse
Node-cache: cache=29000MB, maxblocks=464000*65536, allocation method=11
Mid: pgsql, cache=29000
Setting up table: planet_osm_nodes
Setting up table: planet_osm_ways
Setting up table: planet_osm_rels
Using built-in tag processing pipeline
Using projection SRS 3857 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
Setting up table: planet_osm_line
Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon
Setting up table: planet_osm_roads

Reading in file: russia-latest.osm.pbf
Using PBF parser.
Processing: Node(347886k 399.9k/s) Way(31888k 51.02k/s) Relation(871680 759.97/s)  parse time: 2643s

Reading in file: password=xxxxxxxx
node cache: stored: 347886451(100.00%), storage efficiency: 51.32% (dense blocks: 7163, sparse nodes: 309598190), hit rate: 100.00%
```

I was confused, cause big node(22Gi),ways and polygon (both 7+Gi) have been created...

Comment: Make sure that **russia-latest.osm.pbf** is at the end of your command line, not somewhere in the middle. See https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql#usage for details.